# Filling out a form field automatically

Tags: javascript, html

I have a form in my admin panel through which I want the admin to have the rights to create a new page.

In this form there are two fields, category name and URL.

I want that when the admin fills out the category field the URL field gets automatically filled.

Suppose the admin enters the category name as audits and reporting then the URL should be filled as audits-and-reporting.php.

Here is my code:

```
  <td height="26" align="right" ><span class="required">*</span> Name :</td>
  <td>
    <input type="text" name="category_name" value=""   placeholder="Your Catgeory Name" size="40" /> <a href="#" class="url_from_title">Create URL</a><br />

    <div id="error_url_creator" class="red"></div>
  </td>
 </tr>
 <tr class="trOdd">
<td height="26" align="right"><span class="required">**</span> Page URL :
</td>
</tr>
```

How can this to be done?

Comment: this can be done using php and a little bit of brain power

Comment: @shahsani why use ajax? you just need some regex to create a valid url address and a hidden/disabled filed

Comment: @madalinivascu I know but my purpose of asking the question was to get an idea of how to do it! -_- Which I didn't really get from any of the comments here.

Comment: Ignore the Ajax and php comments,  they are not relevant to your question, look at string replace and toLowerCase

Comment: This question lacks any attempt from the OP to trying to solve the issue at all. There are multiple libraries and/or tutorials about this if you simply do some searching.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a JavaScript event method which replace spaces with hyphen "-". This will be fired on change/blur of textbox.
e.g.

```
   function getUrl(txtBoxText){
    return txtBoxText.toLowerCase().replace(/ /g,"-")+”.php”;
}
```

You can change hyphen as per your requirement.

Comment: You should probably replace more characters than just space. Most "string to slug"-libraries (and CMS's) replaces anything except alpha numeric characters, spaces and underscores.

Answer (score -1):

Use an html like this in which you use data-* as you would use with data-timestamp.

```
    <input class="category-input" type="text" data-category-url="audits-and-reporting.php" name="category_name" value="" placeholder="Your Catgeory Name" size="40" />
```

And then you can fetch it with jQuery's data function which you would use like:

```
   $(input).data("category-url");
```

In this case. Only that you would use it whenever your desired event (posibly focusout or blur) arises on your category-input elements. It could be like

```
$(".category-input").on("focusout blur", function(){
       var url = $(this).data("category-url");
       // Now you can place that url wherever you want
});
```

**---EDIT---**

If the url has to be dynamicly generated use [javascript's encodeURI](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeURI.asp) instead of the data-* thing.

Comment: it is supposed to  be dynamic. The values are supposed to be generated dynamically.

Comment: try using javascript's encodeURI as I mention in my edit then.

Comment: Where is the jQuery tag?

Answer (score -2):

**HTML**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><span class="required">*</span> Name :</td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="category_name" value="" placeholder="Your Catgeory Name" size="40" id="Catname" />
            <a href="#" class="url_from_title" onclick="CreateURL()">Create URL</a><br />

            <div id="error_url_creator" class="red"></div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="trOdd">
        <td>
            <span class="required">*</span> Page URL :
            <input type="text" id="CreatedURL" name="URL" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**Javascript**

```
 function CreateURL() {
    var CatName = document.getElementById("Catname").value;
    var URL = CatName.toLowerCase();
    var replacedString = URL.replace(/ /g, "-");
    var FinalURL = replacedString + ".php";
    document.getElementsByName('URL')[0].value = FinalURL;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer but it simply doesn't work.

Comment: @prak24 , I tried it and it is working. Wait i'll make a fiddle and you can check it there.

Comment: @prak24 , Please check the post and run the code snippet. It is working.

Comment: But I want the value to appear in input type="text" i.e in a form field so that i can post these values. I don't want it appear in label

Comment: Instead of `label` you can have `<input type='text' />` field  and put the value in that textbox and when you will submit your form textbox value will be submitted too.

Comment: But that doesn't really happens with innerhtml. But I figured out a solution for it, so no worries

Comment: I updated my post. In case you want to review it. :-) I am glad you find a solution.